# Spying a function called by jQuery 'change' with RequireJS and Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I'm rather new at both RequireJS and Jasmine so I'm having a little trouble setting up a few basic tests to start with. I've found a lot of info on how to set up the two together, and have it working. However I have an interesting problem I can't seem to fix.

Unfortunately I'm not sure the best way to word the problem so here's some code:

main.js:

```
require(['jquery', 'manipulate'], function($, Manipulate) {
  var manipulate = new Manipulate;
  $(document).on('change', 'td input', function() {
    manipulate.pushChange();
  });
});
```

manipulate.js:

```
define(function() {
  function Manipulate() {
    //
  };

  Manipulate.prototype.pushChange = function() {
    return true;
  };

  return Manipulate;
});
```

ManipulateSpec.js:

```
describe('Manipulate', function() {
  var manipulate;

  beforeEach(function() {
    var flag = false;

    // Load fixtures into the HTML
    loadFixtures('ManipulateFixture.html');

    // Require the manipulate.js file
    require(['jquery', 'manipulate', 'main'], function(jQuery, Manipulate) {
      manipulate = new Manipulate;

      // Define any spies
      spyOn(manipulate, 'pushChange');

      flag = true;
    });

    // Wait for manipulate.js to load before running tests
    waitsFor(function() {
      return flag;
    });
  });

  it('should call pushChange after changing a cell', function() {
    $('td input').eq(0).trigger('change');
    expect(manipulate.pushChange).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

(Removed some extra code)

If I `console.log` inside `Manipulate.pushChange`, it is firing. The problem is, the `Manipulate` object that is being spied on isn't the same object that is passed as an argument in the `main.js` file. So adding `manipulate.pushChange` in my `it()` block makes the test pass.

I found an answer for Backbone.js apps, which calls [`delegateEvents`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents). I'm not sure if there is a similar solution for vanilla Javascript, jQuery, etc. but I can't find one.

Is there a better way to structure my files, potentially putting my jQuery event handlers in the manipulate module? Or just a way to "copy" events between the two objects? I don't even believe using `createSpy` will help me much in this case.

Comment: I think you partially answered your own question. You're not acting on the instance of `manipulate` that's currently under test. I see a couple different ways around the problem: 

1) Consider if it makes sense for `Manipulate` to be a "static" object rather than a "classy" object via prototype. Is instantiating `Manipulate` going to buy you anything? e.g. - `var Manipulate = { pushChange: function () { return true; } };`
2) Figure out a good way of injecting the actual object under test into your jQuery event handler.

Comment: I'll also add that I'm not sure `Backbone.View#delegateEvents` is quite apples to apples here. In Backbone, you can call `this.delegateEvents` to manually wire up all of the events declared in a view's `events` hash. Additionally, jQuery is an optional dependency of Backbone. So if Backbone sees that `$` is `jQuery`, then it'll use jQuery's API to wire up DOM events within the view, rather than doing it via some other means. I know that doesn't really address the root of your question, just an extra tidbit on how Backbone works. :)

Comment: I initially wrote it to have a "constructor" so I could define my event listeners there (forgot to move it from my main.js to there). I got rid of that, made it an object, with an `initialize` function, which I can call whenever I need to attach events. Interesting on the Backbone. I've looked into it but never had much of a reason to so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some problems with your code that make it really hard to test. First you can't test requiereJs modules like the way you try it, if you wanna mock the dependencies. Take a look at this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11439540/184883) for some solutions.

The other problem is that you relay on jquery and DOM events. So most of the time I doesnt try to rebuild the DOM with fixtures for the test. Instead I spy on the jquery object that the event was binded to and call the function by myself. So in for your code

```
$(document).on('change', 'td input', function() {
  manipulate.pushChange();
});
```

you could spy on `$`like this

```
var documentSpy ={on:jasmine.createSpy()};
spyOn(window, "$").andReturn(event); // in a requireJs module mock it like in the SO I've mention above
```

Now when your code bind the event it will just call the spy and you can check if the event was binded correctly:

```
var callback = documentSpy.on.mostRecentCall.args[2]
expect(documentSpy.on).toHasBeenCalledWith('change', 'td input', callback);
// fire the callback
callback();
expect(manipulate.pushChange).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: I wound up getting this working by using most of your answer, but I couldn't get the mocks to work. So instead of using `createSpy` to watch for the `.on()` call, I just spied directly on `$.fn.on`. But besides that, the rest of your code to test worked beautifully. Thanks for the help! My final full test: https://gist.github.com/4674824

Comment: Ah, good to know that it will work this way. Thanks for charing your findings.