# How to stub Backbone View instantiated within another Views render method when Using RequireJS (and Jasmine / Sinon)

Tags: unit-testing, backbone.js, requirejs, jasmine, sinon

I am attempting to write unit tests using Jasmine and Sion but I am struggling to find the equivalent of the following when using RequireJs to load modules:

```
sinon.stub(window, "MyItemView");
```

When using RequireJs, I am unable to stub this way as MyItemView is not attached to the window.

The following is an example of when I need stub the MyItemView:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: '#myElement',
initialize : function() {
    var that = this;
    this.collection.fetch({
        success : function() {
            that.render();
        }
    });
},

render : function() {
    this.collection.each(this.renderItem);
}

renderItem: function(model){
        var myItemView = new MyItemView({model: model});
        $('#myElement').append(myItemView.render().el);
    },

...
```

Now, using Jasmine I can test that the innerHtml contains the expected HTML:

```
it('View should contain correct Html', function(){
            var collectionFetchStub = sinon.stub(this.myCollection, 'fetch').yieldsTo('success', this.myCollection);
            this.view = new MyView({collection: this.myCollection});
            expect(this.view.el.innerHTML).toContain('<li><a href=""> 1 : test </a></li>');

            // Remove Stubs
            collectionFetchStub.restore();
        });
```

However, this test has a dependency on the rendering of MyItemView, which is not ideal for a unit test. What is the best solution to this problem? I am quite a novice to javascript and a solution to this seems complex.

Comment: I can kind of see what you're saying, but if you're testing `MyView` then you don't necessarily care how it's composed (or maybe you do). This version of `MyView` uses a `MyItemView`, but if you rewrite `MyView` then maybe it won't. The question then is, are your original tests of `MyView` still valid? If they aren't, then maybe you were testing things you didn't need to (or shouldn't have).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439540/how-can-i-mock-dependencies-for-unit-testing-in-requirejs/11695463#11695463) on how to stub dependencies with requireJS. There are some solutions. Like testrJs, squireJs or my own little solution. The main idea is to override the requireJs dependency with your spy/stub/mock so you can test only the module.

So in your case you could to stub MyItemView like this:

```
var el = $("<div>test</div>")
var MyItemView = sinon.stub().returns({render: sinon.stub().returns(el)})
```

Then you have to inject the MyItemView stub into your require context and you can test the test div was appended to `$('#myElement')`. This is not ideal, cause all of the DOM stuff but it will work. A better way would be not to render something outside your backbone view. Cause then you can inject a mocked `el` into the view and just test that the append method of your mock was called.