# Stubbing required module in Browserify for Unit Testing

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, sinon, browserify

Ok I've just started to get into Browserify and have had a bit of an issue writing my jasmine tests.  Basically I have a backbone view that is has nested view in it, now for testing purposes I obviously don't want to test the nest view in here as it being tested with it's own unit tests. What I want to do is just stub it out, check that it's being called with the correct

So I have the following

```
nestedView  = require('./nested_view.coffee')

module.exports = class MainView extends Backbone.View
   initialize:(collection, attr)->
     NestedView = if _.isUndefined(attr.Stub) then NestedView else attr.Stub
     @nested_view = new NestedView()
```

Then in my tests:

```
it "Tests my nested view", ->
  Stub =  sinon.stub()
  @mainview  = new MainView(collection:@collection, {SV:Stub})
  expect(Stub).toHaveBeenCalledOnce()
```

While this does work it feels a bit nasty as I'm having to add code to my script just to run the tests.

Does anyone know a nicer approach?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stub Backbone View instantiated within another Views render method when Using RequireJS (and Jasmine / Sinon)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15837017/how-to-stub-backbone-view-instantiated-within-another-views-render-method-when-u)

Comment: Hmm not sure I complete agree although the approach is similar, there is better approaches in requirejs imo.  I'm also not really sure the answer solve my problem, which is stubbing a model and not and element.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out rewireify or proxyquireify. They will allow you to manipulate your "nestedView  = require('./nested_view.coffee')" statement in your test. But yes, you will have to do this for each require statement you want to mock. You also may want to check out Facebook's Jest, that mocks all of your require statements for you automatically.

Comment: Facebook's Jest has quite a few [major] issues: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues