# How to inject a mock into a Dojo class with intern.js

Tags: unit-testing, dojo, amd, code-injection, intern

I've a series of basic tests coded for [Intern 1.4](http://theintern.io/) for my code (server and client) developed on the top of [Dojo Toolkit 1.9](http://dojotoolkit.org/).

Now I want to test classes in isolation, with mock objects instead of the dependencies automatically resolved by the AMD loader.

Here is a set of classes with 'bb' depending on 'aa', with the mock of the 'aa' class, and the test cases I want to verify.

```
/* file <root>/aa.js */
define([], function() {
    return {
        get: function() { return 'aa' }
    };
});
```

--

```
/* file <root>/bb.js */
define([ './aa' ], function(aa) {
    return {
        get: function() { return aa.get() + '-bb' }
    };
});
```

--

```
/* file in <root>/tests/aaMock.js */
define([], function() {
    return {
        get: function() { return 'aaMock' }
    };
});
```

--

```
/* file in <root>/tests/aaTest.js */
define([ 'intern!object', 'intern/chai!assert', '../bb',  ], function (registerSuite, assert,  bb) {
    registerSuite({
        name: 'testbed',

        'bb untouched': function() {
            assert.strictEqual('aa-bb', bb.get());
        },

        'bb with mocked aa': function () {
            require(
                { map: { '*': { 'aa': '<pkg>/tests/aaMock' } } },
                [ '<pkg>/bb' ],
                function(bb) {
                    assert.strictEqual('aaMock-bb', bb.get());
                }
            );
        }
    });
});
```

From the test file above, Intern reports one successful test and one failure. As far as I've been able to trace the Dojo loader (Dojo 2 packaged with Intern), the second reference of the 'bb' module comes from the loader cache.

**Questions:**

- Is it the right approach? Or should I instrument the 'bb' class with a `injectMock()` method that will override the local reference of the 'aa' class with a given 'aaMock' reference?
- I read that RequireJS caches can be [invalidated with `context` and `urlArgs` flags](http://weblog.bocoup.com/effective-unit-testing-with-amd/). Can we do something similar with the Dojo loader?

Note that I did not use the [context-sensitive require](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/modules_advanced/) on purpose as it does not accept a new config.

Thanks, Dom

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to mock dependencies in Intern tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324900/how-to-mock-dependencies-in-intern-tests)

Comment: Yes, that's a duplicate (don't know how I missed it!). Your mention of the `require.undef` to be shipped with Intern 1.5 is what I'm looking for! Any ETA for this update?

Answer (score 2):

While waiting for Intern 1.5 and its `require.undef` feature, I've decided to go with the `injectMock()` approach:

- The class to be tested exposes a method `injectMock()` if `has("mockable-api")` is true.
- Only my Intern configuration call `has("mockable-api", true);`.

There's a little trick:

- Intern configuration relies on `intern/node_modules/dojo/has` (as it does not know where my own copy of the Dojo toolkit is);
- My class relies on the same dependency. If it would rely on `dojo/has` (the one from my Dojo local copy), it would never get the truthy `has("mockable-api")`;
- To be able to run the same class in the browser, I've instrumented the `dojoConfig` definition with a mapping that replaces the dependency on Intern:

  ```
  dojoConfig = {
      has: { 'mockable-api': false },
      packages: [{ name: 'dojo', location: '/libs/dojo' }, ... ],
      map: { '*': { 'intern/node_modules/dojo/has': 'dojo/has' } }
  }
  ```

Now each test case can inject mocks that replace the original dependencies. Then, even tests dealing with the DOM (via `dojo/dom` or `dojo/dom-construct`, for example) can work in isolation.

The only weird behavior reported by Intern is related to some circular dependencies identified by the AMD loader, as you can see below with `dojo/dom-construct`. Hopefully, it does not impact my tests...

`Circular dependency: *11 -> tests/allTests -> controllers/tests/mainTest -> controllers/main.js -> dojo/dom-construct -> dojo/dom-attr -> dojo/dom-prop
-> dojo/dom-construct`

Comment: The circular dependencies in that code are handled correctly by that code, so the warning can be ignored.