# Stub a dependency function in sinon

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, amd, sinon, intern

I am using intern as testing framework and sinon for mocking the data. I dont want to hit the server for http requests during unit tests. So I have created a module that returns the data in deferred.promise as shown below:

```
define(["require", ..], function(require, ...) {
  function fakerequest(){
    dfd = new Deferred();
    setTimeout(function(){
      deferred.resolve(data);
    },100);
    return dfd.promise;
  }
  return fakerequest;
});
```

And this is the original AMD request module that hits an external server with http request:

```
define(["require", ..], function(require, ...) {
  function request(){
    dfd = new Deferred();
    ... 
    return dfd;
  }
  return request;
});
```

And this the module that I wanted to test. And it uses the request function for some data:

```
define(["require", ..], function(require, ...) {
  var QuerySomething = {
    execute: function(){
      ...
      return request();
    };
  }
  return QuerySomething;
});
```

Now I want to test the QuerySomething module but I dont want it to use the original request function but instead use the fakeRequest function. So in my intern test, I used sinon to stub the original request with the fake one.

```
registerSuite({
  name: 'QuerySomething',

  setup: function(){
    stub = sinon.stub(request, "request", fakeRequest);
  },

  teardown: function () {
    stub.restore();
  },

execute: function(){
  queryTask.execute(query).then(function(results){
    console.log(results);
  });
}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property request as function
```

Can someone please let me know how to mock the dependency function?

Comment: Do you have methdo `request.request`? From where do you have object `request` when you are stubing method on it?

Comment: Actually, I don't have a request object. I have an AMD module called request which returns the request function. I know that I have used the wrong syntax. But couldn't find any resource on how to stub a function without an object. Is there any work around to do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sinon can't directly stub a AMD dependency. When it stubs an object method, it's replacing the method on the object with a new method. Say you have an object `foo` with a method `bar`. `bar` is a property on `foo`. Your code calls `foo.bar()` at some point.

Now you stub the `bar` method. The property `bar` on `foo` is modified to point at a new function (the stub). When your code calls `foo.bar()` now, the stub is actually executed since `foo.bar` points at the stub instead of the original function.

The standard way to mock something like your request module with AMD is [to use a loader map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324900/how-to-mock-dependencies-in-intern-tests). With a loader map, you can configure your QuerySomething module to load the fake request module as a dependency rather than the real one during testing.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I actually did that and got it working... I used the map in the intern's loader and mapped the request to fakerequest for QuerySomething module.. Thank you..