# setup for headless unit testing using requirejs

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, requirejs

This seems to be a kind of Search for the Holy Grail, but I'm looking for a setup for a JavaScript unit testing environment. The requirements are:

- testing Requirejs AMD modules
- isolate each module by mocking out dependencies
- testable in the browser during development
- testable in a headless environment for continuous integration

Everything except the headless mocking seems to be straight forward.

So far, I've tested [JS-Test-Driver](https://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/), [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/index.html), and [Phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/), and for mocking, I've used [Squire](http://phantomjs.org/) and [Isolate](https://github.com/tnwinc/Isolate) -- as well as an implementation of the code in [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11695463/279608) and nothing seems to work exactly right. The main problem I keep running into again and again is that the test framework returns before all the tests have run -- primarily because the mocks need their own `require()` dependencies.

Any help (or scaffold) would really help!

**[edit]**

I've put up a basic, working [Karma project](https://github.com/scriptfoundry/karma-requirejs-mock) on Github with some sample mocked tests, using chai-expect as the matching library. I'll try to add more useful documentation, but if you're familiar with Karma, it should be pretty simple to extend. Just `git clone` and then `npm install` to get it running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually every test framework allows you to do asynchronous tests and starting tests manually which should be what you need.

#### QUnit

For QUnit you need to set the `autostart` setting to `false` to enable kicking tests off manually:

```
QUnit.config.autostart = false;

require(['test/qunit/test.js'], function() {
    QUnit.start();
});
```

If you load things asynchronously during tests, just use QUnits `stop()` and `start()` methods:

```
test('something that loads asynchronously', function() {
    stop();
    define(['something'], function(sth) {
        ok(sth, 'Something loaded');
        start();
    });
});
```

#### Mocha

Mocha works very similar:

```
/*globals mocha */
mocha.setup('bdd');

require([ 'test/mocha/test.js' ], function() {
    mocha.run();
});
```

And asynchronous tests are even nicer by declaring a parameter which will be the callback for your spec:

```
describe('an async something', function() {
    it('loads the dependency', function(done) {
        define(['something'], function(sth) {
            ok(sth, 'Something loaded');
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

This should usually work. One thing to keep in mind that tests might not always run in the same order if you load your test files with RequireJS.

Comment: It looks like Mocha will definitely do the trick, because every test (or assert) can take a callback, making it asynchronous. I'm still having trouble with Mocking, though. I'll try using Squire with Mocha, now.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about mocking. If you build your application in a way that every widget is decoupled (kind of like its own application) and test them separately, you can start testing the lowest level widgets first and then the ones that are composed of other widgets (because you know that the ones you rely on should already work). One of the few things I usually mock out are AJAX responses and things like e.g. SocketIO.

Comment: Agreed. There are times though when you definitely want to isolate logic completely, or at least strip out the sorts of things that might cause race conditions and such. I think I'm going to stick with the mocking code in the answer [Koberle made in this other thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11695463/279608). It's extremely simple and works great in Karma.