# Dependency Injection with javascript / coffeescript to aid testability

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, dependency-injection, coffeescript, jasmine

I'm implementing some testing with [`Jasmine`](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/) in my web app.  I'm using [`Coffeescript`](http://coffeescript.org/) to write my models, services and view models.

```
class MyViewModel
  constructor: ( @options ) ->
    @alert = new Alert
      elementId: 'my-alert-element-id'

    @service = new MyService
      alertId: @alert.elementId
```

Now I write a test in jasmine

```
describe 'MyViewModel', ->
  sut = null

  beforeEach ->
    sut = new MyViewModel()

  afterEach ->
    sut = null

  describe 'constructor()', ->
    it 'creates a new instance of the ViewModel', ->
      expect( sut ).not.toBeNull()
```

So the problem here is that I've got dependencies on `alert` and `service` in my `viewModel`.  This is making the tests annoying to write and maintain.

Are there libraries out there for depency injection in Javascript.  I've used several `.net` libraries like [`castle windsor`](http://docs.castleproject.org/) and `ninject`.

Or should I just be adopting a certain type pattern.  I should say that I'm using [`knockout`](http://knockoutjs.com/) and when I'm using the viewmodel in my actual application it looks something like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function () {
    var viewModel = new MyViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
  });

</script>
```

Instead of me creating my own object I'd be asking the injection framework for an instance of `MyViewModel` I assume.

I'm looking for advice on what pattern or library to adopt to make my testing a bit easier and help decoupling my javascript classes from each other.

---

Libs I've found:

- [Wire](https://github.com/cujojs/wire/blob/master/docs/get.md#getting-poly) - Only ECMA 5+ and I need to support older browsers
- [Dijon](https://github.com/creynders/dijon-framework) - Looks ok but I haven't tried it yet.

---

EDIT: What I ended up doing

- I adopted RequireJs and moved all my objects into AMD style modules
- I use Jamine to run the tests
- I use Sinon to create mocks and stubs
- I use Squire to inject mocks and stubs into my system under test

See coffeescript example of a test file

```
define ['squire', 'sinon' ], ( squire, sinon ) ->
  describe '==== a view model ====', ->
    sut = null
    testContext = null

    beforeEach ->
      testContext =
        squireInjector: new squire
        stubService: sinon.stub()
        stubJquery: sinon.stub()
        someCallbackSpy: sinon.spy()

      testContext.squireInjector.mock( 
        'jquery', squire.Helpers.returns( stubJquery ) )

      testContext.squireInjector.require ['aViewModel'], ( viewModel ) =>
        sut = new viewModel
          service: testContext.stubService
          someCallback: testContext.someCallbackSpy

      waitsFor( -> sut? )

    afterEach ->
      sut = null
      testContext = null

    describe 'the constructor method should', ->
      it 'create a new instance of the view 
        model and have required dependencies', ->
        expect( sut ).toBeDefined
        expect( sut.service ).toBeDefined
        expect( sut.someCallback ).toBeDefined

    describe 'the next method should', ->
      it 'increment the route id by one', ->
        # Arrange
        sut.routeId = 5

        # Act
        sut.next()

        # Assert
        expect( sut.routeId ).toEqual( 6 )
        expect( testContext.someCallbackSpy.called ).toBe(true)
```

Comment: Great write up! Thanks

Comment: Jasmine also supports creation of mocks and stubs. Any specific reason to Sinon ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use requirejs, and one of this solutions:

- [creating a new context and override dependencies with your mocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439540/how-can-i-mock-dependencies-for-unit-testing-in-requirejs)
- [Testr](https://github.com/mattfysh/testr.js)
- [SquireJs](https://github.com/iammerrick/Squire.js/)

Or you just mock the prototypes of your Objects.

```
jasmine.spy(Alert.prototype, 'someFunction')
```

Btw. you can use wire.js with older browser using a shim. From the docs:

> To support non-ES5 legacy browsers, wire.js 0.9.x requires poly 0.5.0
>   or higher. You can clone or download poly into your project, or
>   install it via yeoman/bower:

Comment: Would moving to require be a complete rewrite of all my js to work under their framework?

Comment: This would be the case with any solution, but as you're using coffeescript classes wich can be simply converted in a requirejs module it shouldn't be that much work.

Answer (score 2):

There is a library that provides very similar functionality to `ninject` for Coffeescript, [honk-di](https://github.com/markchadwick/honk-di). [Here's a helpful write up](http://labs.vistarmedia.com/2014/05/22/dependency-injection-with-coffeescript.html) about it. Your example would become something more like this:

```
class MyViewModel
  elementId:  inject('element.id') # Inject a constant
  alert:      inject(Alert)
  service:    inject(MyService)

  constructor: ->
    @alert.elementId = @elementId
    @service.alertId = @alert.elementId
```

Then, your tests will work just like they would with `ninject`, `Guice`, or similar. You describe your testing objects in a module/binder, and simply ask an injector for your class at test time.

```
describe 'MyViewModel', ->
  sut = null

  beforeEach ->
    # Assuming you've made mocks or simplified classes for
    # Alert and MyService which are set up in TestModule.
    # `element.id` will also need a definition.
    injector = new inject.Injector(new TestModule())
    sut = injector.getInstance(MyViewModel)

  afterEach ->
    sut = null

  describe 'constructor()', ->
    it 'creates a new instance of the ViewModel', ->
      expect( sut ).not.toBeNull()
```