# Jasmine Tests in a Durandal App

Tags: unit-testing, requirejs, jasmine, durandal

**Scenario**
I am in the process of writing a number of jasmine tests for a Durandal based app that I am in the process of writing.  The Durandal documentation suggests that the way to write tests is like

**ViewModel**

```
 define([
        'knockout',
        'plugins/router',
        'services/unitofwork',
        'services/logger',
        'services/errorhandler',
        'services/config'
    ],
        function (ko, router, unitofwork, logger, errorhandler, config) {
            var uow = unitofwork.create();
            var searchTerm = ko.observable();
            var results = ko.observableArray([]);
            var search = function () {
              uow.myySearch(searchTerm).then(function (data) {
                results(data);
                logger.log(data.length + ' records found', '', 'myViewModel', true);
              });
            };
            var vm = {
              search : search,
              searchTerm : searchTerm,
              results : results
            };
    });
```

**Test**

```
define(['viewmodels/myViewModel'], function (myViewModel) {
    describe('Stuff im testing', function(){
        it('returns true', function () {
            expect(true).toBe(true);
        });
    });
});
```

and for most of my tests this works great.

**Problem**
How do I mock/stub/fake a module that has been passed into ViewModel.  For instance the UnitOfWork module so that it always returns a standard set of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For unit testing check out https://github.com/iammerrick/Squire.js/ a dependency mocker for requirejs. Another technique using require context is described in [How can I mock dependencies for unit testing in RequireJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439540/how-can-i-mock-dependencies-for-unit-testing-in-requirejs).

For integration testing you might look into something like http://saucelabs.com (selenium based).

For some grunt tasks that helps setting up unit tests in phantomjs|browser see https://github.com/RainerAtSpirit/HTMLStarterKitPro (Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of the repo). I'd love to see some mockup integration, so send a pull request if you feel inclined.

Comment: Thanks for the links.  I will check them out.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out
https://github.com/danyg/jasmine-durandal

this is a library that I'm working on, in a few days will have the ability to test widgets too.