# How can I mock RequireJs loader plugin responses in unit tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, requirejs, squirejs

The code I'm trying to test relies on RequireJs [loader plugins](http://requirejs.org/docs/plugins.html). Example with [requirejs/text](https://github.com/requirejs/text):

```
require(['text!templates/foo'], function (data) {
  // handle loaded data
});
```

For a specific unit test, I'm trying to mock the response for `text!templates/foo` and override with one relevant for the test:

```
it('should load a template', function (done) {

  // TODO: mock 'text!templates/foo' here to return 'mock_data'

  // templateViewer uses the text plugin internally to do the actual loading
  templateViewer.templateFor('foo', function (error, templateData) {
    expect(templateData).toEqual('mock_data');
    done();
  });

});
```

I've looked at RequireJs dependency mock [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439540/how-can-i-mock-dependencies-for-unit-testing-in-requirejs), especially [Squire.js](https://github.com/iammerrick/Squire.js) but it seems they are all suited for mocking regular dependencies and not plugin responses.

I've also looked at stub libraries like [sinon](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#stubs) to maybe replace the actual `require` call but that seems problematic.

What's the recommended practice? I prefer not to replace the entire `text` plugin with a mock one in my requirejs configuration, just override some of its responses in specific tests.

My setup is node+mocha+requirejs

**Edit**

Please see this example fiddle project to see my issue with Squire:

http://runnable.com/VUBoI0ex6v9Gs-BJ/squirejs-with-plugins-for-node-js-and-hello-world

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will mock what you'd get from requiring `text!foo/x.html`. Plugins are not special, you just need to mock the entire path, including the plugin name.

```
var requirejs = require("requirejs");
var assert = require("assert");

requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: __dirname,
    packages: [
        {
            name: "squire",
            location: "node_modules/squirejs",
            main: "src/Squire"
        }
    ]
});

var x;
before(function (done) {
    requirejs(["squire"], function (Squire) {
        var injector = new Squire();

        injector.mock("text!foo/x.html", "foo").require(["text!foo/x.html"],
                                                   function (_x) {
            x = _x;
            done();
        });
    });
});

it("foo", function () {
    assert.equal(x, "foo");
});
```

The problem you run into with the example code you added to your question is that you use the global `require` instead of using a `require` passed by your loader. You should add `require` as a dependency:

```
define(['require', ....], function (require, ....) {
```

The `require` module is special and reserved by RequireJS. It returns a reference to the `require` function. You must use it, for instance, when you use RequireJS's contexts so that a module loaded in a specific context uses a `require` function that is bound to that context. SquireJS also needs you to do this so that it can trap your calls to `require`. The global `require` bypasses SquireJS.

Comment: Tried that, not working since the plugin is used with require() and not define(). Please see this example fiddle:

http://runnable.com/VUBoI0ex6v9Gs-BJ/squirejs-with-plugins-for-node-js-and-hello-world

Comment: "Not working?" The code I've put in my answer was tested and runs perfectly fine.

Comment: Take a look at the runnable I posted. Your code works perfectly of course, but the use-case I have is slightly different. The runnable shows the difference.

Comment: You, my friend, are awesome! Thanks a million, I completely missed the part about passing require in RequireJs docs