# How to mock specific RequireJs dependencies while unit testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, mocking, dependencies

I use [qUnit](http://qunitjs.com/) in the browser to unit test my pet project. The module I am unit testing can look like:

```
// Filename: views/base.js

define(['../manager'], function(Manager){

  return Backbone.View.extend({

   //...

});
```

I want to mock out the dependency `"../manager"` (manager.js)
I tried using [testr.js](https://github.com/mattfysh/testr.js) and [Squire.js](https://github.com/iammerrick/Squire.js/) both of which suggest to modify the path to the config for paths.

Example:

```
testr.config({
    root: '../',
    baseUrl: 'src',
    stubUrl: 'tests/mocks',
    ignore: ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'],
    whitelist: ['tests/unit']
});
```

The problem I see after I run this code is that the module I am testing (base.js) is also mocked out as well as unit test module because they are included as dependencies in unit-test runner:

```
define([
  'tests/unit/test-unit',
  'tests/unit/views/base-view-unit',
], function(Test, BaseViewTest){

// ...

});
```

Console output:

```
http://localhost:63342/project/tests/mocks/js/views/base.stub.js 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:63342/project/tests/mocks/tests/unit/views/base-view-unit.stub.js 404 (Not Found)
```

I could add those two files into white list but that won't resolve my problem.

**I guess my question is: how to mock out the deps of the file I am testing right now but not the file itself when it is included into the unit test runner?**

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've found the possible answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439540/how-can-i-mock-dependencies-for-unit-testing-in-requirejs) saying that I need to use the separate config.js to Load Mock Dependencies From Different Paths. Yuk.